# Split a string on different substrings, but conserve those substrings

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split the following string:

```
Hello how are you<br>Foo bar hello
```

Into

```
"Hello", " how", " are", " you", "<br>", " Foo", " bar", " Hello"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: explode on space and <br>

Comment: What do you have so far? Will it always be space and `<br>`  you are wanting to split from?

Comment: what do you want the output to be if you have space before <br>?

Comment: Thanos, in that case it should be " <br>". The whole reason for this is that I'm using a text diff engine that will consider "Hello<br>Something" as a single word.

Comment: you could just replace the <br> with a space then, or strip all html ?

Comment: But I need to preserve those tags :(, just need the engine to consider at as a different word. In other words, I need the engine to split words on spaces, newlines, and tags.

Comment: all tags? the question keeps changing

Comment: Yes, all tags. Althogh, the question is the same, I can easily adapt the result if its splitting on "<br>" to include any other needed tags. Thanks!

Comment: sure list ever one, but it really helps if you ask a more detailed question to start with. every answer below uses <br> only as that s what you asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make things harder than you have to. Use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag, and capture the `<br>`:

```
$str = 'Hello how are you<br>Foo bar hello';
$array = preg_split( '/\s+|(<br>)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r( $array);
```

**[Output:](http://3v4l.org/R4hp9#v525)**

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Hello 
    [1] => how 
    [2] => are 
    [3] => you 
    [4] => <br> 
    [5] => Foo 
    [6] => bar 
    [7] => hello
)
```

**Edit:** To include the space in the following token, you can use an assertion:

```
$array = preg_split( '/(?:\s*(?=\s))|(<br>)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

So, the goal of `preg_split()` is to find a spot in the string to split. The regex we use consists of two parts, `OR`'d together with `|`:

1. `(?:\s*(?=\s))`. This starts off with a non-capturing group `(?:)`, because when we match this part of the regex, we do not want it returned to us. Inside the non-capturing group, is `\s*(?=\s)`, which says "match zero or more whitespace characters, but assert that the next character is a whitespace character". Looking at our input string, this makes sense:

   ```
   Hello how are you<br>Foo bar hello
        ^   ^
   ```

   The regex will start from left to right, find "Hello{space}how", and decide how to split the string. It tries to match `\s*` with the restriction that if it consumes any space, there needs to be one space left. So, it breaks up the string at just `"Hello"`. When it continues, it has " how are you
   Foo bar hello" left. It starts the match again, trying to match from where it left off, and sees " how are", and does the same split as above. It continues until there are no matches left.
2. Capture `<br>`, with `(<br>)`. It is captured because when we match this, we want to keep it in the output, so capturing it along with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` causes it to be returned to us when it is matched (instead of being completely consumed).

This [results in](http://3v4l.org/bNlUD):

```
array(8) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(5) "Hello" 
    [1]=> string(4) " how" 
    [2]=> string(4) " are" 
    [3]=> string(4) " you" 
    [4]=> string(4) "<br>" 
    [5]=> string(3) "Foo" 
    [6]=> string(4) " bar" 
    [7]=> string(6) " hello" 
}
```

Comment: Is there any tweak you can think of that will prepend each space to the result? For example:
[0] => "Hello", [1] => " how",... (notice the space on " how")

Comment: @Boni - Yes, that shouldn't be too bad with an assertion. Give me a few minutes, I will update my answer.

Comment: @Boni - See my updated answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: You rock! Thank you very much sir, just for curiousity, can you explain me what does the changed part do?

Comment: @nickb I borrowed your regex and used it in my answer. I quoted you, but your regex is interseting. without the negative 1 I was getting the first `<` cutoff.

Comment: @Boni - Sure, I've updated my answer with an explanation. Now that I'm looking at it, since you don't have multiple spaces in between the words, you can change the regex to just `/(?=\s)|(<br>)/`, it should still work.

Comment: doesn't actully deal with all tags as requested.

Comment: @Dagon - What tags? The output of my final edit is identical to the desired output in the OP, is it not?

Comment: in his comments he says he wants to split on all tags, not just <br>

Comment: @Dagon - "All tags" is ambiguous and open-ended. So, there is no viable solution with those requirements. My post answers the question in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but simple enough:

```
$data = 'Hello how are you<br>Foo bar hello';
$split = array();
foreach (explode('<br>', $data) as $line) {
  $split[] = array_merge($split, explode(' ', $line));
  $split[] = '<br>';
}
array_pop($split);

print_r($split);
```

Or version 2:

```
$data = 'Hello how are you<br>Foo bar hello';
$data = preg_replace('#\s|(<br>)#', '**$1**', $data);
$split = array_filter(explode('**', $data));
print_r($split);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

1. Explode the string with space as a delimiter
2. Loop through the parts
3. Use [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) and check if part contains the given tag -- `<br>` in this case
4. If it does, explode the string again with the tag as the delimiter
5. Push all the three items into the result array
6. If it doesn't, then push it into the result array

Code:

```
$str = 'Hello how are you<br>Foo bar hello';
$parts = explode(' ', $str);
$result = array();

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if(strpos($part, '<br>') !== FALSE) {
        $arr = explode('<br>', $part);
        $result = array_merge($result, $arr);    
        $result[] = "<br>";
    }
    else {
        $result[] = $part;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => how
    [2] => are
    [3] => you
    [4] => Foo
    [5] => <br>
    [6] => bar
    [7] => hello
)
```

### [Demo!](http://codepad.org/dZtIZrHh)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief solution. Replace `<br>` by (space `<br>` space) and split using space:

```
<?php
   $newStr=str_replace("<br>"," <br> ","Hello how are you<br>Foo bar hello");
   $str= explode(' ',$newStr);   
?>
```

Output of `print_r($str)`:

```
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => how
    [2] => are
    [3] => you
    [4] => <br>
    [5] => Foo
    [6] => bar
    [7] => hello
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the `preg_split` pattern from [@nickb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18884314/654953)'s answer:

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello how are you<br>Foo bar hello';

$array = preg_split('/\s/',$string);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $a = preg_split( '/\s+|(<br>)/', $value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    if(is_array($a)) {
        foreach($a as $key2 => $value2) {
            $result[] = $value2;
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => how
    [2] => are
    [3] => you
    [4] => <br>
    [5] => Foo
    [6] => bar
    [7] => hello
)
```